# php multidimentionals array print in html table view

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [Zahid] => Array
        (
            [physics] => 35
            [maths] => 30
            [chemistry] => 39
        )

    [Amir] => Array
        (
            [physics] => 30
            [maths] => 32
            [chemistry] => 29
        )

    [Kundan] => Array
        (
            [physics] => 31
            [maths] => 22
            [chemistry] => 39
        )

    [Narayan] => Array
        (
            [physics] => 31
            [maths] => 22
            [chemistry] => 39
        )

)
```

I want to show the given array in this HTML table format. I have tried to use a foreach loop but it's not showing the correct format. How can I do it?

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Zahid</th>
        <th>Amir</th>
        <th>Kundan</th>
        <th>Narayan</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>physics : 35</td>
        <td>physics : 30</td>
        <td>physics : 31</td>
        <td>physics : 31</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>maths : 30</td>
        <td>maths : 32</td>
        <td>maths : 22</td>
        <td>maths : 22</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>chemistry : 39</td>
        <td>chemistry : 29</td>
        <td>chemistry : 39</td>
        <td>chemistry : 39</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: "I have try to foreach loop but it not showing coeect format."  Show the code that you tried and the resulting output.

Comment: It would be nice if you included a var_export of the array also.

Comment: You probably need to re-order your data in array according to subjects rather than names something like Array ( [Physics] => Array ( [Zahid] => 35 [Amir]=>30 ) ) etc. That way it will be easier to loop through rows.

Comment: @Andreas - I wrote this converter for just such a thing http://artisticphoenix.com/2018/11/11/output-converter/  It can convert `print_r` or `var_dump` to `var_export` - it works pretty well, don't mind the rest of my site as I never seem to get the time to work on it.  You can find the source code for it on [GitHub](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/tree/master/Lexers/OutputConverter)

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to use a nested foreach loop on the main array, because you'll end up with students as rows and subjects as columns, which is the opposite of what you want. I assume that's what you're getting when you say it's not showing the correct format. You can get a list of subjects from one student:

```
$subjects = array_keys(reset($students));
```

Then iterate that to get your rows, and inside each row iterate the list of students to get their grade for the subject that row is showing.

```
// each subject is a row
foreach ($subjects as $subject) {

    // each student is a column
    foreach ($students as $student => $grades) {
        echo "$subject : $grades[subject]";
    }
}
```

That's the general idea, I'm sure you can figure out the table markup so I left that out for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

I do not ask why you will ignore the reference to the students... 
so the most simple approach to solve try this:

```
    // student
    $students = array_keys($array);

    //physics 
    $physics = array_column($array, 'physics');

    //maths
    $maths = array_column($array, 'maths');
```

and finally do whatever you want with the data retrived from $array.